# Windows - sound recording program giving noise

Tags: windows, audio, wav

I wrote the following program to record the sound through soundcard in windows and print the PCM data from buffer of waveheader. But it gives only the data 32600-32700. Is the problem with my soundcard? I have used WAVE_MAPPER which automatically selects the source...Please help me

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){



HWAVEIN microHandle;
WAVEHDR waveHeader;
MIXERCAPS mixerCaps;
WAVEFORMATEX format;
//HWAVEOUT hwo;    // play

while (1){


const int NUMPTS = 44100 * 0.01;   // 10 seconds
int sampleRate = 44100;      //can get frequency from here
short int waveIn[NUMPTS];   // 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
// for 8-bit capture, you'd use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit types

MMRESULT result = 0;

format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;      // simple, uncompressed format
format.wBitsPerSample = 8;                //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
format.nChannels = 1;                     //  1=mono, 2=stereo
format.nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate;       //  22050
format.nAvgBytesPerSec = format.nSamplesPerSec*format.nChannels*format.wBitsPerSample / 8;
// = nSamplesPerSec * n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
format.nBlockAlign = format.nChannels*format.wBitsPerSample / 8;
// = n.Channels * wBitsPerSample/8
format.cbSize = 0;

result = waveInOpen(&microHandle, WAVE_MAPPER, &format, 0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

cout << "checking step 1" << endl;

if (result)
{
    cout << "Fail step 1" << endl;
    cout << result << endl;
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}

// Set up and prepare header for input
waveHeader.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
waveHeader.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS;// *2;//why *2
waveHeader.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
waveHeader.dwUser = 0L;
waveHeader.dwFlags = 0L;
waveHeader.dwLoops = 0L;
waveInPrepareHeader(microHandle, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

// Insert a wave input buffer
result = waveInAddBuffer(microHandle, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

int NumOfMixers = mixerGetNumDevs();
cout << NumOfMixers << endl;

//cout<<(char*)mixerCaps.szPname<<endl;

//system("pause");

cout << "checking step 2" << endl;

if (result)
{
    cout << "Fail step 2" << endl;
    cout << result << endl;
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
//system("pause");

result = waveInStart(microHandle);

cout << "checking step 3......started recording..." << endl;

if (result)
{
    cout << "Fail step 3" << endl;
    cout << result << endl;
    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}

// Wait until finished recording
do { cout << "still"; } while (waveInUnprepareHeader(microHandle, &waveHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR)) == WAVERR_STILLPLAYING);

waveInStop(microHandle);
waveInReset(microHandle);
//waveInUnprepareHeader(hwi, lpWaveHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
waveInClose(microHandle);

//printing the buffer
for (int i = 0; i < waveHeader.dwBufferLength; i++)
{
    if (waveIn[i] > 0)
        cout << i << "\t" << waveIn[i] << endl;
}


}
    system("pause");
    //waveInClose(microHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you're mixing the usage of 16 and 8 bits. You're buffer is defined as a 16-bit short. Notice your own comment:

```
short int waveIn[NUMPTS];   // 'short int' is a 16-bit type; I request 16-bit samples below
// for 8-bit capture, you'd use 'unsigned char' or 'BYTE' 8-bit types
```

Yet, when defining the audio format you are specifying 8 bits:

```
format.wBitsPerSample = 8; //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
```

Either change `format.wBitsPerSample = 16` or if you want 8 bit audio then do something like this:

```
unsigned char waveIn[NUMPTS];
...
format.wBitsPerSample = 8; //  16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade

//printing the buffer
for (int i = 0; i < waveHeader.dwBufferLength; i++)
{
    cout << i << "\t" << (int)waveIn[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the 8-bit number fit into the 16-bit variable and give the correct result? I have copied the program from somewhere on net

Comment: Yes it will fit...exactly twice. and thats the problem. The waveIn API is going to fill the memory as if it were an array of bytes. When you return into your code and treat it as an array of a different type doesn't make it so.